# python child class __set__ not working

Tags: python, class, subclass

I was following the advice of "python cookbook" on topic "Implementing Data Model or Type System" and there's code as follows:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, **opts):
        self.name = name
        for key, value in opts.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

class Unsigned(Descriptor):
    def __init__(self, name=None, **opts):
        super(Unsigned, self).__init__(name, **opts)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print 'child set value: ', value
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Expected value > 0")
        super(Unsigned, self).__set__(instance, value)
```

However, it code of the `__set__` part seems not working for the subclass. Cause when tried:

```
test = Unsigned("Judy") #this works fine, the __init__ part
test = -9 # there's no error raised, but the __set__ function in the child class is supposed to raise such error \
```

since no negative is allowed for this type checking class

I can't tell where the problem could possible be.. the initialization works fine..
Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a nice catch, I often interview candidates, this one is a good question for entry level candidates :)

Comment: this works for python3.. but in python2.7 I guess it's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descriptors are supposed to live inside class declarations, like this:

```
class Foo(object):  # don't need (object) in 3.x
    bar = Unsigned('bar')
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html):

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods in the descriptor protocol.

You're then meant to instantiate the class and use the descriptor as an attribute:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bar = -7  # this should throw an exception
```

Descriptors will not do anything if you try to assign to them directly:

```
Foo.bar = -7  # just replaces the descriptor with -7
```

...nor if you don't put them into a class in the first place:

```
baz = Unsigned('baz')
baz = -7  # just set the variable to -7
```

Comment: Thanks! it works inside the class. But why in python 2.7 it still doesn't work? .. is there a way to make it work in python 2.7...

Comment: @JudyJiang: Descriptors work just fine in 2.7, assuming you're using new-style classes (which inherit from `object`) everywhere.  If you're experiencing a problem, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: but for this piece of code, I tried test = Foo(), then test.bar = -2 and it just went through.... should I change some field in the code ..?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would happen.  It sounds as if you declared `Foo` as a classic class (without the `(object)` part), but I can't tell without seeing all of your code.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't put "object" in Foo. now it's working!